# CloudFront Behavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I am having some issues when adding custom headers using Lambda.

When I use my lambda function as a cloudfront event it works for using https://www.example.com or http://www.example.com for instance default (*) behavior.

When I add new behavior for a specific path or paths for instance https://www.example.com/path or https://www.example.com/* cloudfront returns an error.

Validations are being done using curl --header https://www.example.com & https://www.example.com/path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed the CloudFront response from Viewer Response to Origin response and received expected headers.